# How to insert on-fly query data to HBase using Hive

Tags: hive, hbase

I am new in Hbase and Hive. Can someone please explain me how to insert data into Hbase using Hive?

I found a lot of information regarding to this, but all of them are talking about exactly the same thing. In other words, they are inserting into Hbase table from another already existing table.

In my case it is different. I have an application which reads some data from users and sends to the server and incoming data needs to be written in Hbase table. How can I do that?

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE hive_table (key INT, username STRING, password STRING, address STRING) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key, user:val')
TBLPROPERTIES('hbase.table.name'='hbase_table');
```

How can I insert following record to my Hbase table which is hbase_table using Hive:

```
key=123, username='something', password='pass', address='somewhere';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hive does not provide any support for the ANSI SQL `INSERT INTO table VALUES (a, b, c, d)` insert statement. If you have another table or file that contains the data in question, you can make the insert using something like

`INSERT INTO hive_table SELECT key, username, password, address FROM foo`

If you want to interact with HBase directly, I suggest using:

1. [HBase shell](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html#shell_exercises)
2. [Phoenix](http://forcedotcom.github.io/phoenix/#upsert_values)
3. [Kiji](http://www.kiji.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeremiah. Then how can I store user data when user gets registered in a web site and at the same time providing task distribution? I think HBase itself does not provide any task parallelism. It should be used at least with MapReduce to achieve distribution of tasks. As Hive is good alternative for MapReduce, I wanted to use Hive in this case.

Comment: When you communicate with HBase to write data, you specify a row key. That row key determines which Region Server is responsible for handling a single row of data. Hive is *not* a database; Hive is a job translator - in effect, it turns HiveQL into MapReduce. To push data into HBase data, you'll need to use an HBase client library like the three I mentioned.